# big-O-calculator: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, big-o, quicksort

I'm trying to calculate the speed of two functions that I have, this one uses quick sort method. I am using [this page](https://pypi.org/project/big-O-calculator/) to download and use the big O calculator, and test the speed using this. But when I try to execute it, it throws me this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`. I'm not sure why, otherwise the program works fine.

```
from bigO import BigO

data = "studentMockData_AS2.txt"
students = []
with open(data, "r") as datafile:
  for line in datafile:
    datum = line.split()
      students.append(datum)
    
size = len(students)

def quicksort(array, lowest, highest):
  if lowest < highest:
    pi = partition(array, lowest, highest)
    quicksort(array, lowest, pi - 1)
    quicksort(array, pi + 1, highest)

def partition(array, lowest, highest):

    pivot = array[highest]

    ptr = lowest - 1

    for student in range(lowest, highest):
      if array[student] <= pivot:
        ptr += 1
        (array[ptr], array[student]) = (array[student], array[ptr])

    (array[ptr + 1], array[highest]) = (array[highest], array[ptr + 1])

    return ptr + 1

lib=BigO()

comp = lib.test(quicksort, students, 0, size-1)
print(comp)
```

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve]! Also, the error message is effectively self-explanatory. Search for the message online to get further info. Concerning your problem, why are you taking `lower` from a `list` object? That is the question you should ask yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Big0 test func parameters:

```py
def test(**args):
    functionName [Callable]: a function to call.
    array [str]: "random", "big", "sorted", "reversed", "partial", "Ksorted", "string", "almost_equal", "equal", "hole".
    limit [bool] = True: To break before it takes "forever" to sort an array. (ex. selectionSort)
    prtResult [bool] = True: Whether to print result by itself
```

You are passing a list ***students*** to Big0.test() method where it is expecting a **str**. Use 'random' instead.

Comment: I get this error instead: line 403, in test
    result = functionName(nums)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: quicksort() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lowest' and 'highest'. Same thing happens if I try to input values for those.

Comment: Sorry @paparonnie, lib.test() doesn't accept custom parameters. you can try lib.runtime() to pass your custom parameters. Everything is clearly documented in this [link](https://github.com/Alfex4936/python-bigO-calculator).